# Android MediaCodec - encode audio on the fly into aac

Tags: android, encoding, aac

I'm trying to use the [MediaCodec](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) from Android to encode raw audio data into aac.
I worked my way through the Andoid documentation which lacks a lot. I'm currently able to record audio using [AudioRecord](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) and do the encoding on the fly.

The problem is that the generated output doesn't seem to be valid. No player can play it back and the [MediaExtractor](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html) can't open the file. Latter is probably because the output is not wrapped into a valid container. There is no clear documentation about how to handle the input buffer size for encoders. So I tried to fill every input buffer completely before I queue it again with no success. I also tried to submit the END_OF_STREAM_FLAG with the last buffer also with no success.

Has someone successfully used the MediaEncoder and can provide some information on how to use it right? Is there a possibility to generate valid media containers like mpeg4?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Choose a container for it. I prefer adts.

Copy the the payload data into an aray that is large enough for your container, just add on your bits. So after scouring the internet for my solution I worked some snippet into place

```
    profile =( configParams[0]>>3 )&0x1f;

    frequency_index = (this.configParams[0]&0x7) <<1 | (this.configParams[1]>>7) &0x1;

    channel_config = (this.configParams[1]>>3) &0xf;

    int finallength = encoded_length + 7;       
    ENCodedByteArray[0] = (byte) 0xff;
    ENCodedByteArray[1] = (byte) 0xf1;
    ENCodedByteArray[2] = (byte) ( ((profile - 1) << 6) + (frequency_index << 2) +(channel_config >> 2));
    ENCodedByteArray[3] = (byte) (((channel_config & 0x3) << 6) + (finallength >> 11));
    ENCodedByteArray[4] = (byte)( (finallength & 0x7ff) >> 3);
    ENCodedByteArray[5] = (byte) (((finallength & 7) << 5) + 0x1f) ;
    ENCodedByteArray[6] = (byte) 0xfc;
```

Using something like

```
            byte chunkADTS[]=new byte[info.size + 7];
            fillInADTSHeader(chunkADTS,info.size);
            outputBuffers[bR].get(chunkADTS,7,info.size);
            buffer.pushData(chunkADTS);
```

Comment: On Android 4.3 and above you can use the [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) class to package MediaCodec's output into a MPEG-4 container. As a bonus, when AAC is contained in an .MP4 it doesn't require the per-packet ADTS headers. I've got a quick n' dirty example [here](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/HWEncoderExperiments/blob/audioonly/HWEncoderExperiments/src/main/java/net/openwatch/hwencoderexperiments/AudioEncoder.java).

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed example?  I'd like to implement this solution but I'm unclear on how it all fits together.  I'm downloading an AAC-ATDS audio file and trying to play it locally.  I can play it locally if I decode the aac into PCM using a MediaCodec decoder and then feeding it into an audio track.  I would prefer to re-encode it into a format playable with the regular media player. (I don't know why the ATDS headers on the downloaded file do not work, but I believe the MediaCodec decoder strips them; if they were actually there).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MediaCodec AAC decoder for decoding the raw data again. Just be sure to set it up correctly as mentioned in [Decoding AAC using MediaCodec API on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942201/decoding-aac-using-mediacodec-api-on-android)