# Is it impossible to Decode Raw AAC byte stream with MediaCodec on Android4.1 (API 16)?

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

Is it impossible to Decode Raw AAC byte stream with MediaCodec on Android4.1 (API 16)?

Do I need to add some header??

This is the subsequent Quesion of
[PCM -> AAC (Encoder) -> PCM(Decoder) in real-time with correct optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804390/android-mediacodec-pcm-aac-encoder-pcmdecoder-in-real-time-with-correc)

Probably related to

[Decoding AAC using MediaCodec API on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942201/decoding-aac-using-mediacodec-api-on-android)

[How to initialize MediaFormat to configure a MediaCodec to decode raw AAC data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784781/how-to-initialize-mediaformat-to-configure-a-mediacodec-to-decode-raw-aac-data)

[How to use MediaCodec without MediaExtractor for H264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742047/how-to-use-mediacodec-without-mediaextractor-for-h264)

Anyone any thought?

Answer (score 0):

Raw AAC should work, however you have to packetize your stream correctly before sending to the decoder, i.e. each buffer should contain a full aac frame.

Comment: How dude; how? Examples please :)