# Can Android play a ADTS AAC file?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, mp4, aac

I use code below generated a aac audio file. And the file plays fine on my windows machine. But it cannot be played on my android device using a MediaPlayer. What should I do to make the file playable on a android device? Thanks!

```
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16 * 44100);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    recorder.setAudioChannels(2);
    recorder.setOutputFile(mTempFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Can Android play a ADTS AAC file?..."*

Not with default apps. Only if you code such an app. Use the [**`MediaCodec`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API to manually send each of your aac frame's bytes to the decoder.

If you can handle bytes and familiar with aac frame structre, then check these as starting points :

[Decoding AAC using MediaCodec API on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942201/decoding-aac-using-mediacodec-api-on-android)

[PCM -> AAC (Encoder) -> PCM(Decoder) in real-time with correct optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804390/pcm-aac-encoder-pcmdecoder-in-real-time-with-correct-optimization)

> *"But it cannot be played on my android device using a MediaPlayer... What should I do to make the file playable on a android device?..."*

The `aac` data must exist inside a **container** format like `m4a` or `mp4`.
 MediaPlayer (strangely) does not play raw aac data, yet does not expect raw `mp3` to be contained.

*note:*
When placed inside one of the above, you will lose the ADTS header for each frame (since that information will now exist in other parts of the container's metadata).

Comment: Thank you very much! It's much more complicate than I thought initially... I searched how to put aac in a m4a container. People suggested mp4Box and ffmpeg, is there a way to do it using native Android API? Will the MediaMuxer class do the job?